# F# sequence comparison

Tags: f#

I have implemented a Fibonacci Sequence generator as follows

```
let getNext upperLimit current= 
        let (e1, e2) = current
        let next = e1 + e2
        if next > upperLimit then None
        else Some (next, (e2,next))

let fib upperLimit = (0,1) |> Seq.unfold (getNext upperLimit) |> Seq.append [0;1]
```

and my test code is

```
[<Test>]
member Spec.``fib not exeeding 20 should be 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13``()=
    let expected = seq [0;1;1;2;3;5;8;13] 
    let result = fib 20
    let expectedSameAsResult = (expected = result)
    printfn "Expected: %A  Result: %A result length: %d" expected result (Seq.length result) 
    Assert.That expectedSameAsResult
```

The test failed and the printed result is

*Expected: [0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 5; 8; 13]  Result: seq [0; 1; 1; 2; ...] result length: 8*

When I used a for loop to print every element in result, I got exact same elements in the expected sequence.

So, what is the difference between the expected and result sequence?

Edit: my implementation can be found at https://github.com/weima/EulerProblems/tree/master/EulerProblems

**Edit: To answer John Palmer's answer**
I just wrote a test in F# interactive window

```
 let a = seq[1;2;3]
 let b = seq[1;2;3]
 let c = a = b;;
```

The result I got is 
val a : seq = [1; 2; 3]
val b : seq = [1; 2; 3]
val c : bool = true

So F# can do structural comparison to sequences too.

**Edit to reflect to Gene Belitski's answer**
I have changed the test to

```
[<Test>]
member Spec.``fib not exeeding 20 should be 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13``()=
    let expected = seq [0;1;1;2;3;5;8;13] 
    let result = Problem2.fib 20
    let comparedResult =  Seq.compareWith (fun a b -> a - b) expected result  
    let expectedSameAsResult = (comparedResult = 0)
    Assert.That expectedSameAsResult
```

And it worked now. Thanks! but I still don't understand why a simple seq[1;2;3]=seq[1;2;3] works, but my test case doesn't.

Comment: You have been affected by the compiler not doing what you expect - try `a=(b|> Seq.map id);;`

Comment: @WeiMa: to understand what's going on try a bit different simple case with genuine sequences `seq {1..3} = seq {1..3}` in FSI - this expression equals to `false`

Comment: Thanks, guys, I got it now.

Comment: Or use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whilst you may expect that `a=b` would compare elements for sequences it infact `a=b` computes reference equality.

You can see this with something like

```
seq {1..3} = seq {1..3}
```

which returns false.

However, in some cases when you use constants you get confusing results, in particular

```
seq [1;2;3] = seq [1;2;3]
```

returns true, which is confusing.

To avoid this issue, you need to do something like

```
 let test a b = Seq.fold (&&) true (Seq.zip a b |> Seq.map (fun (aa,bb) -> aa=bb))
```

to compare element wise.

Alternatively, you can use `Seq.compareWith` as outlined in Gene's answer.  However, this requires that the elements also implement a comparison operator as well as equality, which may not be the case for some things like discriminated unions which implement `=` but not comparison.

Comment: in his blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f-1-9-7.aspx  Don Syme said that f# supports "structural" equality, I would assume comparing two sequences fall into this category

Comment: @WeiMa This is true for `list` but not for `Seq`

Comment: I think the `list` vs `Seq` difference is due to `list` having a fixed size, whereas `Seq` could have an indeterminate size (how would you compare infinite sequences?).

Comment: Sequences are not compared by reference equality.  The `Equals` method is usually used by the generic implementation of `=` (there are some minor subtleties here - arrays are treated specially, for instance).  For lists, `Equals` is overridden to implement structural equality, but for other types of sequences the implementation may fall back on the default of reference equality (or do something else).

Answer (score 18):

Adding to John's answer: sequence equality can be determined with [`Seq.compareWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) library function:

```
let compareSequences = Seq.compareWith Operators.compare
```

Then sequence equality would be value of the expression

```
let expectedSameAsResult = (compareSequences expected result = 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

MSDN for [Operators.seq<'T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353788.aspx) function says: Builds a sequence using sequence expression syntax.
If you look into [its implementation](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3493) you'll see that it is basically just identity function that has special meaning for the compiler only when used with sequence expression syntax. If you call with list - you'll get the same list back (upcasted to seq<_>).

Re structural equality, per F# spec:

*by default, record, union, and struct type definitions—called structural types—implicitly include 
compiler-generated declarations for structural equality, hashing, and comparison. These implicit declarations 
consist of the following for structural equality and hashing:*

```
override x.GetHashCode() = ...
override x.Equals(y:obj) = ...
interface System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable with 
    member x.Equals(yobj: obj, comparer: System.Collections.IEqualityComparer) = ...
    member x.GetHashCode(comparer: System.IEqualityComparer) = ...
```

*The following declarations enable structural comparison:*

```
interface System.IComparable with 
    member x.CompareTo(y:obj) = ...
interface System.Collections.IStructuralComparable with 
    member x.CompareTo(yobj: obj, comparer: System.Collections.IComparer) = ...
```

*For exception types, implicit declarations for structural equality and hashings are generated, but declarations for structural comparison are not generated. Implicit declarations are never generated for interface, delegate, class, or enum types. Enum types implicitly derive support for equality, hashing, and comparison through their underlying representation as integers*

So lists (essentially unions) - support structural equality and sequences - not. To check elements pairwise you can also use Seq.forall2

```
let isEqual = (s1, s2) ||> Seq.forall2 (=)
```

Comment: Seq.forall2 doesn't do what you need for strict structural equality, particularly if the two sequences are not the same length. `Seq.forall2 (=) [1;2;3] [1;2;3;4] ;;
val it : bool = true`

Answer (score 5):

For anyone finding this answer who just wants an easy way to compare two sequences, there's an alternative to Seq.compareWith:

There's a .NET method `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`. I use this all the time when testing.

Example usage:

```
let sequenceA = seq { 1..5 }
let sequenceB = seq { 1..5 }

Enumerable.SequenceEqual (sequenceA, sequenceB) // True
```

Answer (score 1):

### The reason:

Structural equality is not supported for sequences.

If you think of a `seq` as a .NET `IEnumerable<T>` perhaps this makes more sense? Here `seq [1;2;3] = seq [1;2;3]` is an unfortunate coincidence. Consider a non-pure `seq`:

```
let rnd = System.Random()
let x = seq { yield rnd.Next() }
printfn "x is %A" x
printfn "x is %A" x
```

Result:

```
x is seq [372511654]
x is seq [1026368248]

val rnd : System.Random
val x : seq<int>
```

### The obvious answer:

Use `list` instead of `seq` here.

```
[<Test>]
member Spec.``fib not exeeding 20 should be 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13``()=
    let expected = [0;1;1;2;3;5;8;13] 
    let result = fib 20 |> Seq.toList
    let expectedSameAsResult = (expected = result)
```

### The details:

See the other answers.