# Check if a list and array are equal F#

Tags: arrays, list, f#, compare

I am trying to compare a list and an array and see if they are equal. Lets say we have a list `list = [1;2;3;4]` and an array `ar = [|1;2;3;4|]`. The function should return `true` if equal and `false` if not equal. I did it like this:

```
let list = [1;2;3;4]
let ar = [|1;2;3;4|]

let list' = Array.toList ar
(list = list')
```

So basically what I am doing is simply convert and compare two lists.. My question is is there any other way to do this, I mean which do not simply convert between list and array and which do not rely entirely on library functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that both lists and arrays (as well as most other collections) implement the `seq<'a>` interface (`IEnumerable<T>` in the .NET terms) and so you can just pass them to the functions from the `Seq` module without any conversions. This is just using an interface, so there is no overhead.

The easiest function I can think of for checking whether two sequences are the same is `forall2`, which takes two sequences and checks that a predicate holds for the elements pairwise. In this case, the predicate is just equality test `(fun a b -> a = b)` which you can abberviate as `(=)`:

```
let list = [1;2;3;4]
let ar = [|1;2;3;4|]

Seq.forall2 (=) list ar
```

Comment: `Seq.forall2` doesn’t actually solve this problem correctly when the two sequences have different lengths, because it ignores the longer sequence’s extra elements. E.g. If `list` is `[1;2;3]`, this solution will still return `true` when it should be `false`.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways you could do this. Here's one that compares the elements pairwise:

```
if list.Length = ar.Length then
    Seq.zip list ar
        |> Seq.forall (fun (a, b) -> a = b)
else false
```

Comment: The question was about standard library functions. `Seq.compareWith` exists already.

Answer (score 2):

[F# docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences#sorting-comparing-and-grouping) say:

> You compare two sequences by using the Seq.compareWith function. The function compares successive elements in turn, and stops when it encounters the first unequal pair. Any additional elements do not contribute to the comparison.

Which in your case becomes oneliner:

```
0 = Seq.compareWith (Comparer<_>.Default) list ar
```

Didn't check if it compiles. Use the [Comparer.Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1?view=net-5.0) to compare primitives, otherwise, for complex custom types you may need to provide your own.

Answer (score 2):

With Linq;

```
Enumerable.SequenceEqual (list, ar)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17101734/3342984)

```
let l = [1;2;3;4]
let a = [|1;2;3;4|]
let result = Seq.compareWith Operators.compare l a
```