# F# Bjorklund algorithm: convert while-loop to recursive function: type-constraint issue

Tags: algorithm, f#, type-constraints

I’m doing the deep dive into f# finally. Long time c-style imperative guy - but lover of all languages. I’m attempting the Bjorklund algorithm for Euclidean Rhythms. Bjorklund: Most equal spacing of 1’s in a binary string up to rotation, e.g. 1111100000000 -> 1001010010100.

https://erikdemaine.org/papers/DeepRhythms_CGTA/paper.pdf

I initially based my attempt off a nice js/lodash implementation. I tried from scratch but got all tied up in old concepts.

https://codepen.io/teropa/details/zPEYbY

Here's my 1:1 translation

```
let mutable pat = "1111100000000" // more 0 than 1
//let mutable pat = "1111111100000" // more 1 than 0

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101329/f-sequence-comparison
let compareSequences = Seq.compareWith Operators.compare

let mutable apat = Array.map (fun a -> [a]) ( Seq.toArray  pat )
let mutable cond = true
while cond do
    let (head, rem) = Array.partition (fun v -> (compareSequences v apat.[0]) = 0) apat
    cond <- rem.Length > 1
    match cond with
    | false -> ()
    | true ->
        for i=0 to (min head.Length rem.Length)-1 do
            apat.[i] <-apat.[i] @ apat.[^0]
            apat <- apat.[.. ^1]

let tostring (ac : char list) = (System.String.Concat(Array.ofList(ac)))
let oned = (Array.map (fun a -> tostring a) apat )
let res = Array.reduce (fun a b -> a+b)  oned
printfn "%A" res
```

That seems to work. But since I want to (learn) be as functional, not necc. idiomatic, as possible, I wanted to lose the while and recurse the main algorithm.

Now I have this:

```
    let apat = Array.map (fun a -> [a]) ( Seq.toArray  pat )

    let rec bjork bpat:list<char> array =
        let (head, rem) = Array.partition (fun v -> (compareSequences v bpat.[0]) = 0) bpat
        match rem.Length > 1 with
        | false -> bpat
        | true ->
            for i=0 to (min head.Length rem.Length)-1 do
                bpat.[i] <-bpat.[i] @ bpat.[^0]
            bjork bpat.[.. ^1]

    let ppat = bjork apat
```

The issue is the second argument to compareSequences: bpat.[0] I am getting the error:

*The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type constraints*

I'm a bit confused since this seems so similar to the while-loop version. I can see that the signature of compareSequences is different but don't know why. apat has the same type in each version save the mutability. bpat in 2nd version is same type as apat.

while-loop: `char list -> char list -> int`

rec-funct  : `char list -> seq<char> -> int`

I will say I've had some weird errors learning f# that ended up having to do with issues elsewhere in the code so hopefully this is not a lark.

Also, there may be other ways to do this, including Bresenham's line algorithm, but I'm on the learning track and this seemed a good algorithm for several functional concepts.

Can anyone see what I am missing here? Also, if someone who is well versed in the functional/f# paradigm has a nice way of approaching this, I'd like to see that.

Thanks
Ted

EDIT:

The recursive as above does not work. Just couldn't test. This works, but still has a mutable.

```
    let rec bjork (bbpat:list<char> array) =
        let mutable bpat = bbpat
        let (head, rem) = Array.partition (fun v -> (compareSequences v bpat.[0]) = 0) bpat
        match rem.Length > 1 with
        | false -> bpat
        | true ->
            for i=0 to (min head.Length rem.Length)-1 do
                bpat.[i] <-bpat.[i] @ bpat.[^0]
                bpat <- bpat.[.. ^1]
            bjork bpat
```

Comment: You need to put parentheses around `(bpat:list<char> array)`. Otherwise the type annotation applies to `bjork`, not to `bpat`

Comment: Yikes. I have run into that before and am just not easily noticing the precedence's. But this lesson may stick. Thank You. Make an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around `(bpat:list<char> array)`. Otherwise the type annotation applies to `bjork`, not to `bbpat`:

```
let rec bjork (bbpat:list<char> array) =
  ...
```

Also note that calculating length and indexing are both O(n) operations on an F# linked lists. Consider pattern matching instead.